# Why this access by slice work but not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

`my_name = 'Tlaloc-ES'`

And I am trying the slices the first try is the anagram with this

`my_name[-1:-(len(my_name)+1):-1]`

That return:

> 'SE-colalT'

Then the position `-(len(my_name)+1)` is for `'T'` but when try to use the next slice:

`my_name[-(len(my_name)+1)]` this return a error:

> string index out of range

but with `my_name[-(len(my_name))]` not, and this return `T`

The answer is why for get `T`, in some cases I need plus one and in another cases I do not need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is the slice you created (`-1:-(len(...`) create a generator from -1 to -10 which is technically the number from -1 to -9 (-10 not included). So using it as an index option (`len(my_name) + 1`) means its outside the length of `my_name`. Remove the +1 and it should work

Answer (score 1):

`-(len(my_name)+1)` would be off by 1

```
string = 'word'
len(string) => 4
string[-len(string)] = 'w'
-(len(string)+1) => -5
```

you cant index past your boundaries in native python
the reason your first line works is because your end point can be outside your boundaries and the iterator would stop when it reaches the end